# AWS SES mail account setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I am trying to create an application in which I forward an email to AWS SES, have a lambda function parse that email, extract the required information, and store it in a database. I don't want to store in S3.

I registered for a Route53 domain and received a domain name (example.com). I want to forward emails from my gmail address to an alias in my domain (test@example.com). I created a rule-set in SES, and verified my domain (example.com).

I can't figure out how to create email accounts in my domain (example.com). I would like to create something like test@example.com, where I could forward emails from my personal gmail account. Anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the steps in the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-getting-started-receipt-rule.html). By default all emails for any address in the domain will be sent to your Lambda function when you create the receipt rule. You will have to specify an address (test@domain.com) in the first step of creating a receipt rule to only send emails for that address to the Lambda function.

Comment: I followed the documentation and setup my receipt rule. Is there a way to figure out if the email was forwarded successfully, other then to see if it landed in S3. I'd like to parse the email and move the contents to MongoDB. I see that you can track sending statistics, but not receiving stats.